# Unable to fetch value from Map in groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jsr223

I have a JSON response like below

```
{  
 "id":27,
 "merchant_id":"39",
 "title":"Shorts",
 "subtitle":null,
 "price":100,
 "description":null,
 "images":[  

 ],
 "image_thumbs":[  

 ],
 "options":[  
    {  
     "code":"size",
     "label":"Size",
     "extra_info":"",
     "values":[  
        {  
           "label":"Small",
           "value":"4"
        },
        {  
           "label":"Medium",
           "value":"5"
        }
     ]
    }
 ],
 "options_available":[  
    {  
     "combination":[  
        {  
           "code":"size",
           "value":"Small"
        }
     ]
    },
    {  
     "combination":[  
        {  
           "code":"size",
           "value":"Medium"
        }
     ]
    }
 ],
 "custom_options":[  

 ]
 }
```

I have code in JSR223 Sampler like below:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult

def options = JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.options')
def randomOption = options.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, options.size()))
def code = randomOption.get("code")
vars.put('code1', code)
def values = randomOption.get('values')
def randomValue = values.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, values.size())) as 
String
def FValue = randomValue.get('value')
vars.put('ValueF', FValue)
vars.put('randomValue', randomValue)
```

While debugging the above code, i am able to get the randomValue as either [label:Small, value:4] / [label:Medium, value:5] as expected. But however i am not able to fetch the Value from the output.

```
Getting error as 
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: 
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
java.lang.String.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) 
values: [value]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), next(), grep(), 
getAt(groovy.lang.EmptyRange), grep(java.lang.Object), 
getAt(java.util.Collection)
```

Help is useful and appreciated on this!

Comment: Can you point to the exact line where the code fails? The exception details should show this.

Comment: You have cast `randomValue` to a `String`, then you have called `randomValue.get('value')` so it throws `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
java.lang.String.get() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) ` which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak any soulutions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `randomValue` is an instance of a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) so you can extract "label" as `randomValue.get('label')` and "value" as `randomValue.get('value')` correspondingly.

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter JSR223 Groovy]
2. I don't think you have `prev` shorthand in the JSR223 Sampler, my expectation is that you need to switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) or [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)  instead.

Comment: What should i need to do, if i have more that one child under Options. I mean Options(0), Options(1) etc. Out of which i need to select both